# Tabe field status auto update checking system date using query in mysql & java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

table field status auto update when  checking with  system date and expirydate using query in mysql & java

In my table,

***tbl-member:***

*id, name, expirydate,status*  are fields.

How to use this with **TRIGGER**

(expirydate,systemdate)

```
CREATE
    TRIGGER autoupdation

    trigger_time UPDATE

    ON tbl-member FOR EACH ROW

    trigger_body
```

**how to create trigger_body for this function...**

field expirydate check with system date and auto update the status field.

here is the code use function for check-updation

```
@Override
    public List<Member> FindExpiredMembers() throws ParseException {
        List<Member> memberlistforreturn=new ArrayList<>();
        List<Member> memberlist=getAllMember();
        java.util.Date utilDate=new java.util.Date();
        java.sql.Date sqldate=new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());


        for(Member i : memberlist){
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        java.util.Date exp_Date=sdf.parse(sqldate.toString());
        java.util.Date renew_Date=sdf.parse(i.getRenewDate().toString());
            if(renew_Date.compareTo(exp_Date)<0){
                memberlistforreturn.add(i);
                i.setStatus(true);
                update(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(memberlistforreturn.size());

        System.out.println("working...!!!!!!");
        return memberlistforreturn;
    }
```

using this function the program run on slow

Comment: You want to set value for status if expiry date is later or equal to sysdate. Is that right?

Comment: You are doing this row by agonizing row and also you are reading the whole table. Cant you filter the resulting `List<Member>` with a query?

Comment: @Ravinder yes.. expiry date is later or equal to systemdate

Comment: why you creating new `SimpleDateFormat` for each member?

Comment: @Rembo for parsing each dates of member..

Comment: @PrasanthAR instead of creating a new object of `SimpleDateFormat` for each member, create outside for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be part of your `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger.

```
for each row begin
    if new.expirydate < curdate() then
        set new.status = 1;  -- still active
    else set new.status = 0; -- expired
    end if;
end;
```