# Trigger in mysql used for auto updation got an error

Tags: java, mysql, date

[My Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005458/tabe-field-status-auto-update-checking-system-date-using-query-in-mysql-java?noredirect=1#comment33353695_22005458)  's answer is right. The trigger is got an error

Here i use that in my program the following error occurred

```
2014-02-25T11:51:52.737+0530  ERROR  line 1:2: unexpected token: CREATE
2014-02-25T11:51:52.737+0530  ERROR  line 1:2: unexpected token: CREATE
line 1:2: unexpected token: CREATE
```

This is the code

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void expMember(){


Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
session.beginTransaction();

java.util.Date utilDate=new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date sqldate=new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());

List<Member> members = (List<Member>) session.createQuery(                  
        "from Member where exp_status = 'false' ").list();;

for(Member i : members){

Date exp=i.getRenewDate();

try {

    members = (List<Member>) session.createQuery(   
" CREATE  TRIGGER autoupdation_"+ sqldate +" BEFORE UPDATE  ON tbl-member FOR EACH
      ROW BEGIN IF"+ exp .compareTo(sqldate)+" THEN  SET NEW.status = 1;   
      ELSE SET NEW.status = 0; END IF;END;").list();

}

catch(Exception exception){

}
}
}
```

Comment: FOR EACH ROW for each row begin why have you specified two for each is it a typo? else it may be the root cause of your error.

Comment: It makes no sense in combining java object comparison in creating a trigger. Trigger creation is one time for database but not per call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are Trying to run a native sql query so for those please use `createSQLQuery` instead of `createQuery`

Also Why do you create triggers on fly . Your logic of creating triggers within a loop is wrong. You just need to create one trigger that can be done at database creation itself.

```
The MySQL Table Editor in MYSQL workbench  provides a work space that has tabs used to perform these actions:

Columns: Add or modify columns

Indexes: Add or modify indexes

Foreign Keys: Add or modify foreign keys

Triggers: Add or modify triggers

Partitioning: Manage partitioning

Options: Add or modify various general, table, and row options
```

Please check
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-native-sql-queries-examples/

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-table-editor.html